# Erro ao tentar alterar role de um usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao tentar alterar a role de um usuário :

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> ```
> UserId não encontrada.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para
> ```
>
> obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> ```
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: UserId não encontrada.
>
> Erro de Origem: 
>
>
> Linha 91:             else
> Linha 92:             {
> Linha 93:                 await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(aspnetuser.Id, "Ong");
> Linha 94:                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
> Linha 95:             }
> ```

Ele diz que a userId não pode ser encontrada porém a userId que ele recebe por parâmetro é valida (verifiquei e a mesma constava no db), eu não sei se onde está meu erro, estou fazendo algo de errado ? segue abaixo o método usado para isto :

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AprovarAsync(string Id)
        {
            IdentityRole aspnetuser = new IdentityRole();

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            else
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(aspnetuser.Id, "Ong");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Também já tentei da seguinte forma :

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AprovarAsync(string Id)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser{ Id = Id };
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            else
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Ong");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Porém o erro foi outro :

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details.

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando na construção deste método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua entidade de dados possui uma propriedade que não está corretamente mapeada pelo Entity Framework. No caso a `EntityValidationErrors`.

Recomendo orientar o EF a ignorar essa propriedade - visto que é um estado da entidade e não um valor da mesma.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<BlogMetadata>();
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class BlogMetadata
{
    public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
}
```

Veja mais nesse documento sobre como [incluir e excluir tipos no Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/included-types#fluent-api).